# Black screen after boot if machine starts with the TV off

Tags: boot, video, hdmi

I've built an small HTPC with Ubuntu 16.04 this week. Choosed Ubuntu over OpenElec, because I wan't to run other stuff on it, like Steam for in home streaming.

My problem is:

Every time that I start this machine, with my TV turned off, Ubuntu doesn't show video at all, the screen is just black.
But, when I turn on the machine with the TV turned on, everything goes as supposed, and even if I turn the TV off, and go back turning on, everything works fine.

I don't know for sure, but I think that this is a matter of the boot process, that, when Ubuntu can't find a display to output, it simply doesn't start the video.

I have an Windows Gaming PC hooked on the same TV, and this behavior doesn't happen at all, even if I turn it on, with the TV off.

Also, OpenElec on a Raspberry Pi, doesn't do that. So, I think that is something on how Ubuntu treats the video output on boot.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not much of help in your question, but I have the same issue. That "auto" in xrandr looks for a screen to set the resolution and so on at boot. I have a vague memory of running a "manual" xrandr command at startup to force the resolution in case the screen hasn't been detected,